# Incorrectly placed views with Xcode 9 & iOS 11

Tags: ios, cordova, uiview, uikit

I recently upgraded to Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11. When I first run my project, all of my views were superimposed by the status bar, instead of the status bar being directly on top of my view. On an older version of Xcode, we don't have this issue. A screenshot of my problem is attached here.

Update:

Solved adding this plugin on my cordova application.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

[image: views superimposed by the status bar]

Comment: Please add code.

Comment: @dasdom I don't think is a code problem, some xCode settings can change all my view but I can't find it, and also this happened after updating xCode.

Comment: In which older version of xCode. you don't get issue

Comment: Try to update cordova-plugin-statusbar, and set  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

Comment: @vp2698 xCode 8

Comment: What version of plugin statusbar are you using?

Comment: in plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/plugin.xml file check version= property of <plugin tag.  Or in config.xml under   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.2.1" /> tag

Comment: @Frix33 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.1" />

Comment: Check if you have an error on javascript console by inspect your app in safari.. If you see somewhat about content security policy add this on your index page: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Comment: @Frix33 finally I solved this problem, iPhone X view is still a problem but right now we don't care. Thanks